# Lowest quantity of items in Statistics Problem

Tags: probability, statistics

(I apologize for any english inconsistencies! This was translated from a portuguese original question).

*A drawer contains red and white socks. When two socks are picked randomly (without replacement), the probability of both being red is equal to $1/2$.*

*a) What is the lowest number of red and white socks in the drawer? (since this was translated from portuguese, maybe “lowest” isn’t the best word to use in such a mathematical context)*

*b) What should the lowest number of red and white socks be if the number of white socks is even?*

I actually don't know if I can solve this with basic statistics (which is what I barely grasp). My attempt didn't go very far:

Let's say the number of socks is given by $V + B$. In such case, my first pick has a probability of ${V \over {V + B}}$ of coming red; my second pick has a probability of ${{{V - 1} \over {\left( {V - 1} \right) + B}}}$ of coming red.

So, the information I have would be that:

$$\eqalign{
  & {V \over {V + B}}\left( {{{V - 1} \over {\left( {V - 1} \right) + B}}} \right) = {1 \over 2}  \cr 
  & {{{V^2} - V} \over {{V^2} - V + 2VB - B + {B^2}}} = {1 \over 2} \cr} $$

But I can't really continue, nor do I know if I was supposed to be there in the first place. Any directions would be really appreciated.

Comment: (a) Suppose the drawer contains 3 red socks, and one white sock.  On the first draw, the probability of drawing a red sock is $\frac 34$.  Without replacing it, we have left 2 red socks and 1 white sock.  The chance of drawing another red sock is now $\frac 23$. That gives us $\frac 34\cdot \frac 23 = \frac 24 = \frac 12$ probability of drawing two red socks.

Comment: (b)  We need the number of white socks to be even....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt was on the right track . . .

If you solve for the quadratic equation for $v$, you get
$$v=\frac{2b+1\pm\sqrt{8b^2+1}}{2}$$
which is an integer if and only if $8b^2+1$ is a perfect square.

By inspection, $b=1$ works, yielding the solution pair $(v,b)=(3,1)$, with $v+b=4$.

For the case where $b$ is required to be even, by trial and error, we find that $8(6)^2+1=17^2$, so we get the solution pair $(v,b)=(15,6)$, with $v+b=21$.